# More beautiful way to do if-statement behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods

I have a method in my app that checks to see if some things are true.

```
- (BOOL)isToggleTurnedOn {
    return ([self checkToggleStatus] != [self checkOtherToggle]);
}
```

When this method returns true, I display a modal.

```
if ([Preferences isToggleTurnedOn] == true) {
    NSArray *welcomeTexts = @[
                                ...
                                some data
                                ...
                            ];
    WelcomeController *welcomeController = [[WelcomeController alloc] initWithText:welcomeTexts];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:whatsNewController];

    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Now, this code is not as beautiful as it could by, in my opinion. I'd rather add the presentation of the controller as a parameter of `isToggleTurnedOn`. What's the best way to refactor this?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)isToggleTurnedOn {
    return [self checkToggleStatus] != [self checkOtherToggle]
}
```

Comment: Well, my bad. This example method was just made up on the spot. Although this wasn't the part I was asking about, you're right though.

Answer (score 0):

Drives me crazy to see code like this.  Be more succinct:

```
- (BOOL)isToggleTurnedOn {
    return ([self checkToggleStatus] != [self checkOtherToggle]);
}
```

Comment: Well, my bad. This example method was just made up on the spot. Although this wasn't the part I was asking about, you're right though.

Comment: I saw Avi's answer first. But hey, if it means that much to you, I'll vote yours up as well.

Comment: @duffymo, if SO rep means that much to you, get a life.  Or at least a grip.  Our answers were posted seconds apart.

Comment: _Mine was entered first, yet you vote Avi's answer up but not mine. Seems unjust._  You seem to have a short memory.  You wrote those words.

Comment: Nope, memory's fine.  I wrote the words, but it doesn't mean I'm upset.  An observation, nothing more.